# How to resize or move PDFAnnotation inside PDFPage?

Tags: swift, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I am developing a PDF app using PDFKit (Swift). I have successfully implemented functionality to add drawing into the PDF file using PDFAnnotation subtype Ink. Now, the next step is to make that PDFAnnotation resizable and movable inside the PDF page. How can I add touches or gestures functionality into PDFAnnotation, so that the PDFAnnotation can be resized or moved according to the user requirement. [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2OO5.jpg)

Comment: Hi Sac, did you find a solution for this. Thanks!